# Biggest 10 files in a directory

Tags: c#, filesystems

I need to get the largest 10 files in a directory. What I thought of doing is the following:

```
const noFiles = 10;
biggestFilesArray [noFiles][noFiles]; // file path and file size
const minLength = 0;
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach (string _file in fileEntries)
{
// fill in first 10 files in the array then check if file size bigger than smallest inserted file. If yes then insert it and take smallest out.

}
// Sort Array
```

Is there any built in method that can do this for me?

Comment: What if two files have the same size?  What's the tie break criteria?

Comment: what if directory having sub directories with files?

Comment: You could use Directory.GetFiles(path,"*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: wdosanjos good point but in my case it doesn't matter, I'm trying to monitor DFS staging quota files and only thing I'm worried about is largest 32 files in the replicated folder. If two are the same size then include both of them or if last smallest had a similar file size then just include one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could get all the files in a directory, then take the 10 largest ones using LINQ.

The result will be a collection of `FileInfo` objects.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("someDirectory");

var result = di.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).Take(10).ToList();
```

The [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) classes provide much more info than the call to `Directory.GetFiles()`, which only returns a list of file names.

---

If all you needed in the end was the full file path/name (like `GetFiles()` returns):

```
var topTenNames
  = di.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).Take(10).Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();
```

---

You posted in a comment that you're using `Delimon.Win32.IO` instead of `System.IO`, which has a [newer version](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DelimonWin32IO-Library-V40-7ff6b16c) for .NET 4.0.

I downloaded and checked the source code. Unfortunately, search ing all directories was never implemented. They throw an exception with the same message on several other methods too.

```
public DirectoryInfo[] GetDirectories(string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
{
  if (searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
  else
    return Helpers.FindDirectoriesInfos(this._sFullName, searchPattern);
}
```

I don't think I'd trust this assembly too much. Or I'd make really sure of what I was doing with it. Here's another method in their `DirectoryInfo` class. The `System.IO` version has a `Delete` method that accepts a bool indicating whether you'd like to delete subdirectories recursively. The default is `false`. In this class, it would appear you're being given the same choice, but internally there's a hard-coded `true`.

```
public bool Delete(bool recursive)
{
  return Helpers.DeleteDirectory(this._sFullName, true);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with all sub-directories? Like di.GetFiles(path,"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Grant. Do you recommend using any other assembly? I need to deal with long path names and System.IO doesn't support them. Delimon.Win32.IO is the only one I found.

Answer (score 3):

```
var files = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  .Select(x => new FileInfo(x))
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Length)
  .Take(10).ToList();
```

You can use `GetFiles` method as [Grant Winney's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668057/biggest-10-files-in-a-directory/21668085#21668085), But `EnumerateFiles` method is more efficient

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

Comment: I can understand where `EnumerateFiles` would definitely be advantageous when every file is being manipulated, but in this case the requirement is to find the 10 largest files. With that said, what would be the advantage of using `EnumerateFiles` over `GetFiles` when every file has to be iterated over to find the 10 largest files?

Comment: @MetroSmurf advantage is no need to wait until all the files returned.

Comment: I am using Delimon.Win32.IO instead of System.IO as I deal with file paths longer than 256 characters. EnumerateFiles is not supported in it unfortunately. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Damith: Wouldn't you have to wait to retrieve all the files anyway in order to perform the `OrderByDescending`? That is, how can it order the files by `.Length` without retrieving all of the files in the first place?

Comment: FWIW: I ran a test of using `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` vs `Directory.EnumerateFiles` with a single directory containing 2000 files and `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` was consistently over 2x's a fast. I don't see any advantage of using `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in this scenario. Though `Directory.EnumerateFiles` may not be the best use case in this scenario, it's good to know the option exists to begin manipulating the files before they are all returned.